# Gitlab CI: How to pass error message from script

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In our `.gitlab-ci.yml` we have this job:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./scripts/deploy.sh $INSTANCE_NAME
```

and inside our `scripts/deploy.sh` we have

```
  if ! [ <some error condition> ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
```

When the error is actually triggered and we exit with status 1, we also would like to pass an *error message*, because otherwise we will just get an empty reason in our Gitlab job output:

```
ERROR: Job failed: Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()
```

How can we get an error message to appear inside the brackets instead?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: you can use `your script || true`

Answer (score 3):

How about printing the error message *as part of the script* before the `exit 1`?

```sh
do_something

# check if it succeeded
if [[ ! $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    print_error "The last operation failed."

    exit 1
fi
```

That would show up as:

[image]

That has the benefit of having the same error message appear whether you're running the script manually/locally *or* when running in a CI job.

Comment: I see, thanks!
I still wonder what the right way is to actually fill the brackets in `Reason was ()` with something useful.